# Why does sampling features at each node decrease correlation between trees on a random forest?

Tags: random-forest, cart

The variance of random forest is:

$\rho(x)\sigma^2(x)+(1-\rho(x))\sigma^2(x)/B$, where $\sigma^2(x)$ is tree's variance, $B$ as how many trees there are, and $\rho(x)$ a correlation between two any trees.

If $B$ goes to $\infty$ so that variance goes to $\rho(x)\sigma^2(x)$, the idea behind random forest is random sampling the features in each node to reduce $\rho(x)$ as low as possible, empirically $\rho(x)\leq0.05$, Why this sample reduces $\rho(x)$? I'd guess that's due to each tree will be less equal to each other. I'd like to get as formal as possible explanation for that.